# PDF to Text (Table format)

Tags: text, ocr

I have a problem with converting the following PDF file to text! I the first column of the table but in text everything is messed up. I cannot use regex because sometimes the format of first column appears in the second!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple OCR tool online like http://www.newocr.com/.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use Amazon [textract](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/) or google's [tesseract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/). Both will convert the pdf fine.